# How to assign geom_point colors based on string values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to map some points across a map of the ocean... this is my dataframe (`rik_data`)

```
location      mean_longitude     mean_latitude      
NSTR002         -63.53341          44.47846
NSTR002         -63.53341          44.47846
NSTR001         -63.52704          44.46643  
NSTR001         -63.52704          44.46643  
NSTR003         -63.50115          44.41449       
HFX014          -63.24095          44.21091
HFX014          -63.24095          44.21091
HFX023          -63.22477          44.19080
HFX0165         -63.21937          44.16828
HFX0165         -63.21937          44.16828
HFX020          -63.20010          44.12228
HFX020          -63.20010          44.12228
```

I want to plot these points so that every location starting with "HFX" is one color versus every location starting with "NSTR" is another colour. I'm using this code for the graph.

```
canada = map_data("worldHires", "Canada")


p = ggplot(data = canada) +
  geom_polygon(data = canada, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "lightgrey") +
  coord_sf(xlim=c(-64.5,-62.8), ylim=c(42.7,45), expand = FALSE) +

#HOW TO ASSIGN COLOR BY STRINGS?
  geom_point(data = rik_data,
             mapping = aes(x = mean_longitude, 
                           y = mean_latitude), color = "black",
             size = 4, alpha = 0.5) +
  labs(colour = "Location") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#add8e6"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),

        axis.ticks.y  = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),

        axis.title.y =element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),

        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),

        legend.position = c(0.2, 0.2),
        legend.background = element_blank(),


        text = element_text(size = 25,
                            family = "sans"))
```

Doesn anyone know how to assign red to locations starting with "NSTR" and black to locations starting with "HFX"?

Comment: You would need to add a categorical value to your data frame classifying either "HFX" or "NSTR". Then in ggplot you would add to your aes argument col = "your column with the categorical classification"

Comment: Yeah I tried this using ```rik_data = mutate(col = ifelse(location == "^NSTR", "red", "black"))``` but it doesn't mutate or give me any values

Comment: That's because you're not passing any data to `mutate` in the pipe. It should be `rik_data = mutate(rik_data, col = ifelse(location == "^NSTR", "red", "black"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can create the classification within the ggplot call using a `grepl` (this assumes all cases are either HFX or NSTR). Replace your `geom_point` statement with something like this:

```
geom_point(data = dd,
           mapping = aes(x = mean_longitude, 
                         y = mean_latitude, 
                         color = grepl("^HFX",location)),
           size = 4, alpha = 0.5) +
scale_color_discrete(breaks=c(0,1),labels=c("NSTR","HFX"))
```